# how to write mysql query for the following problem?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

products table **table1** which has item names

| item_cid | item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 |

**table2** which has a current stock

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 |

**table3** which has purchase stock

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | purchase qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | 7 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 | 9 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 2 |

the result I want

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock | purchase qty | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 | null | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 | null | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 | null | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 | null | 44 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | null | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | null | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 | 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 | null | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 | null | 9 | 9 |

the query I tried is not able to retrieve rows from  table 3 in the final result  this what I am getting

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock | purchase qty | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 | null | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 | null | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 | null | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 | null | 44 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | null | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | null | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 | 2 | 60 |

```
SELECT 
   *

FROM
   table2 a
       LEFT JOIN
   table3 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
        JOIN
   table1 d ON  d.item_id=a.item_id
   ORDER BY a.item_id
```

Comment: hey guys any answers for this will appreciated

Comment: 1 hour is too fast to expect an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT item_cid, 
       item_id, 
       item_name,
       SUM(table2.current_stock) current_stock,
       SUM(table3.purchase_qty) purchase_qty,
       COALESCE(SUM(table2.current_stock), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(table3.purchase_qty), 0) total
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (item_cid, item_id, item_name)
LEFT JOIN table3 USING (item_cid, item_id, item_name)
GROUP BY item_cid, item_id, item_name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aeac4b2165c8b8370fbbc082f08b3145

PS. Your tables are not normalized.

Comment: thanks for the answer so working great but small change  this is date wise entry to table2 and the current stock value is the previous date's current stock value and that is added  to the current date purchase value

Comment: "Auntie, give me some water to drink because I want to eat so much that I have nowhere to spend the night." © Another problem - another question.